# Need to find the difference between two XML files in C++

Tags: c++, xml, xerces

Is there any library for this, or does anyone have anything done in Xerces, or any link on how to do this, or any API or any way to do this in Xerces?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think Xerces includes an XML diff algorithm. If you want to implement it yourself, check out [this thesis](http://treepatch.sourceforge.net/report.pdf) and the [accompanying Java code](http://treepatch.sourceforge.net/).